# Error using mod_wsgi, Django and MongoEngine

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, mongoengine

I have set up a Django site with MongoEngine and I am trying to run it using Apache and mod_wsgi with a virtualenv.

It runs fine in development, but under Apache (on ubuntu 14.04.2) I get the following errors in the apache log:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=16130): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/data/.../.../wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/.../.../wsgi.py", line 22, in application
    return get_wsgi_application()(environ, start_response)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/data/.../.../settings.py", line 15, in <module>
    import mongoengine
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongoengine/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import document
  File "/data/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 51
    class EmbeddedDocument(BaseDocument, metaclass=DocumentMetaclass):
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas why this might occur? This is particularly strange to me as I can't find the offending line in the mongoengine source.

My packages are:

```
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.8
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
mongoengine==0.9.0
psycopg2==2.6
pymongo==2.8
static3==0.5.1
```

I'm not sure if it's related, but why is it using `importlib` from `python2.7` and not `python3.4`?

My copy of mongoengine/document.py (installed using `pip install`) does not match the version in git, and has the following:

```
class EmbeddedDocument(BaseDocument, metaclass=DocumentMetaclass):
    ...
    # The __metaclass__ attribute is removed by 2to3 when running with Python3
    # my_metaclass is defined so that metaclass can be queried in Python 2 & 3
```

I'm new to python so I don't understand this, but it seems like a python 3 incompatibility?

Comment: mod_wsgi is somehow using Python 2 instead of Python 3; that syntax is not valid in Python 2. Can you show your Apache configuration and WSGI file?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was using the ubuntu `libapache2-mod-wsgi` package with a virtualenv set up for python 3.4. Changing to `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` fixed it. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the ubuntu `libapache2-mod-wsgi` package version of `mod_wsgi` which is built for Python 2.7 but my virtualenv was built around python 3.4.

The issue was resolved by uninstalling `libapache2-mod-wsgi` and installing `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` which is built for Python 3.4.